# How can I replace multiple words "globally" using regexp_replace in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I need to replace multiple words such as (dog|cat|bird) with nothing in a string where there may be multiple consecutive occurrences of a word. The actual code is to remove salutations and suffixes from a name. Unfortunately the garbage data I get sometimes contains "SNERD JR JR."

I was able to create a regular expression pattern that accomplishes my goal but only for the first occurrence. I implemented a stupid hack to get rid of the second occurrence, but I believe there has to be a better way. I just can't figure it out.

Here is my "hacked" code;

```
  FUNCTION REMOVE_SALUTATIONS(IN_STRING VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
  AS
    REGEX_SALUTATIONS VARCHAR2(4000) := '(^|\s)(MR|MS|MISS|MRS|DR|MD|M D|SR|SIR|PHD|P H D|II|III|IV|JR)(\.?)(\s|$)';
  BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(IN_STRING,REGEX_SALUTATIONS,' '),REGEX_SALUTATIONS,''));
  END REMOVE_SALUTATIONS;
```

I was actually proud that I was able to get this far, as regular expression are not very regular to me. All help is appreciated.

EDIT:

The default for regexp_replace based on my understanding is to do a global replace. But on the outside chance my DB is configured different I did try;

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('SNERD JR JR','(^|\s)(MR|MS|MISS|MRS|DR|MD|M D|SR|SIR|PHD|P H D|II|III|IV|JR)(\.?)(\s|$)',' ',1,0) from dual;
```

and the results are;

```
SNERD JR
```

Comment: Your regexp takes too much: it needs both spaces around the first `JR` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hg94ig/1/). Could you check if lookahead works in oracle: [demo with lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/hg94ig/2/)?

Comment: Yes I see the problem is as you stated. Oracle does not handle look aheads as far as I can tell. I tried your example and also researched it. The example does not work, and what I've read says Oracle does not do look aheads.

Comment: I tried to do it without lookahead: `(^|\b|\s)(MR|MS|MISS|MRS|DR|MD|M D|SR|SIR|PHD|P H D|II|III|IV|JR)(\.?)(\s|$)`, maybe this will help [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hg94ig/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `occurrence` parameter of `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.  The docs says:

> `occurrence` is a nonnegative integer indicating the occurrence of the replace operation:
>
> - If you specify 0, then Oracle replaces all occurrences of the match.
> - If you specify a positive integer n, then Oracle replaces the nth occurrenc

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302

It should look like:

```
...
REGEXP_REPLACE(IN_STRING,REGEX_SALUTATIONS,' ', 1,0 )
...
```

Comment: mrzasa, thanks for your help, I had tried that earlier and did not mention it in my post. BTW the 4th parameter must be > 0. See my edited post above.

Comment: just answered, see below the question

Comment: mrzasa, Using a 0 in the 5th parameter does not work on my DB (11g). I posted an example in an "EDIT" in the original question that you can easily test.

Comment: I _could_ it easily test if I had oracle 11g installed :). As I don't have access to it, I can advise you basing on docs and my regexp knowledge. Or I can stop doing so.

Comment: mrzasa I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, even though you told me where to look, I did not see your post about look ahead. My apologies.

Comment: I see, please, see another comment on the question.