# regexp_replace only captures first instance

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to remove the two periods from a name like `B.J. Smith` using `regexp_replace(name,'[.]','')` but it's only removing the first period. I also tried `regexp_replace(player,'([.])','')` to no avail.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990635/14956277) help? Use the [`occurrences`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302) parameter to determine the number of matches to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `g` flag to replace the matches globally.

```
regexp_replace('B.J. Smith', '\.', '', 'g')
```